# CiviRules Identify how many times a donor contributed in a given time period

Tags: civirules

I am trying to set up a CiviRule to identify if a donor has donated more then 10 times in the last 12 months. I used the Linked Condition xth Day of Contributing By Donor and set it to 10 last 12 months, but that did not work. Is this the right condition to use? If not is there a better way to identify those donors?

Comment: Rachel if you use Summary Fields you will then have a calculated field for number of donations i believe

Comment: I do use summary fields, but I believe Summary fields only tell you a total per year, I wanted to know if they had a total number within the last 12 months.

Comment: Sorry. i skim read the question - I will tweak the title to reflect the 'time period'.

Answer (score 1):

This did work. I was thinking it was 10 or more times in the last 12 months, but it only works if there is exactly 10 contributions.

Comment: Rachel do I understand correctly that the period did not actually work, only the count? Or is it just that you expected 10 or more where it is exactly 10? I want to add an issue so that I can pick it up next time we have some CiviRules funding.

Comment: It was that I expected 10 or more when it was exactly 10. This rule will actually work for me, I just tried it on a contact record that had more then 10 and it did not work.

Comment: Glad it works for you :-)